# Tic-Tac-Toe using python

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I creat a Tic Tac Toe programm but i have a problem, I save user1 guesses in a list and also user2 guesses in another list. I want to compare user1 guess with other user1 guesses and if user1 guess is in the list user musst try one more time. i try several ways to solve this problem but i couldn't solve it, do you have any idea?

guesUser1 => user guess
user1Chooses => this is a list of user1 guesses
[Code in gitHub](https://github.com/rezakhazaei97/Tic-Tac-Toe/blob/master/Tic-Tac-Toe.py)
this is a part of my code

```
    chooseX_user1 = int(input("User1: X(0-2): "))
        chooseY_user1 = int(input("User1: Y(0-2): "))

        while (chooseX_user1 >= 3 or chooseX_user1 < 0) or `enter code here`(chooseY_user1 >= 3 or chooseY_user1 < 0):
            print("invalid X,Y")
            chooseX_user1 = int(input("User1: X(0-2): "))
            chooseY_user1 = int(input("User1: Y(0-2): "))

        guesUser1 = [chooseX_user1, chooseY_user1]

        user1Chooses.append(guesUser1)

        #Start: chack guesUser1 with other user1 guesses in user1Chooses

        #End: chack guesUser1 with other user1 guesses in user1Chooses

        for item in user2Chooses:
            if (guesUser1 == item) or (chooseX_user1 >= 3 or chooseX_user1 < 0) or (chooseY_user1 >= 3 or chooseY_user1 < 0):
                print("invalid X and Y")
                user1Chooses.pop()
                while(guesUser1 == item):
                    chooseX_user1 = int(input("User1: X(0-2): "))
                    chooseY_user1 = int(input("User1: Y(0-2): "))
                    print("invalid X and Y")
                    guesUser1 = [chooseX_user1, chooseY_user1]
                    user1Chooses.append(guesUser1)
                    if guesUser1 == item:
                        print("invalid X and Y")
                        user1Chooses.pop()

        os.system('cls')

        for i in range(0, 3):
            if chooseX_user1 == i:
                for j in range(0, 3):
                    if chooseY_user1 == j:
                        stages[i].pop(j)
                        stages[i].insert(j, "X")

        for line in stages:
            print(' '.join(line))
```

Comment: what is your `user2Chooses`?

Comment: I save user2 guesses in user2chooses

Comment: you have not written the code for inputting `user2chooses`

Comment: This part of my code. I save user2 guesses in user2Chooses and also I have written the code for inputting you can see full code in link in question text

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```py
if guesUser1 in user1Chooses:
  # user1 guess is in the list
```

to check if the guess is in the list, and the same for user2 except the variable is a little bit different.

```py
if guesUser2 in user2Chooses:
  # user2 guess is in the list
```